# Сохранение таймера

Tags: node.js

Есть бот, который отсчитывает несколько таймеров одновременно, у каждого таймера своё значение. Но после перезапуска процесса Node.JS все таймеры сбрасываются и всё начинается сначала. Можно ли как-то эти таймеры сохранять, а после перезапуска восстанавливать своё значение каждому таймеру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так можно делать в принципе с любой бд, просто в mysql есть встроенные функции для взаимодействия с таймштампами

```
async function checkExistTimeout(){
    const timeouts = await mysql.pquery(`SELECT type, (timeStart - 
         (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timeStart))) as 
         timeRemaining FROM timeouts WHERE DATEADD('ms', msTimeout, timeStart) > 
         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`);
    return timeouts
}

async function initRemainingTimeouts(){
     const timeouts = await chechExistTimeout();
     if (timeouts.length){
        for (const timeout of timeouts){
            setTimeout(/*функция в зависимости от типа*/, timeout.timeRemaining)
        }
     } else {
        await mysql.pquery(`INSERT INTO timeouts SET ?, timeStart = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`,[/*объект таймаута */] );
        //инициализация таймаута
     }
}
```